# Is there a testing tool that will make sure a web form is behaving appropriately in response to valid and invalid data?

Tags: forms, validation, testing, selenium, automated-tests

I am looking for a black-box type program/script/Selenium add-on/etc. that will generate different kinds of data, input it into a web form, hit SUBMIT, and test whether the correct response occurred.

I have found programs that would test for one kind of data or another, but I'm looking for a more comprehensive program that would test a wide variety of possible user inputs, so you can verify that the form is accepting or rejecting the inputs in accordance with program specifications.

For example, the program could verify that an error occurs when:

- a number is input into a field that is supposed to be text
- a required field is left blank
- a SQL injection is present
- (checks for other things I have not thought of)

Note 1: I started using Selenium IDE to insert random data, but realized I would have to write a great deal of loops of test cases to test a variety of combinations of different kinds of data. It seems like this would be a very common issue, so I suspected there must be some solution already out there. After much Googling, I could not find one.

Note 2: I realize this can be done via unit testing or other white box methods, but I am looking for a black box solution here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE is great for prototyping your tests, but for anything past trivial solutions you really need to look to tools/frameworks like Watin or Webdriver (Selenium 2) to create useful tests which are maintainable over time. You should also have a look at [Telerik's Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/) (Disclosure: I'm their evangelist for that tool) which is another great functional test solution.

Regardless of which toolset you decide on, it sounds like you're looking for an approach to data drive your various tests: validating combinations of given inputs create expected output conditions. There are a number of posts and articles around on that. I have [a blog post with a brief example of data driving an AJAX menu](http://frazzleddad.blogspot.com/2011/12/31-days-of-testingday-21-data-driving.html) using C# and Webdriver which might be of help.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I have taken a look at your links, and I have moved on to Selenium 2 for my tests. But I've still yet to find a solution that performs these common form handling checks. It seems like such a common issue; I think it would be a shame if everyone is custom writing their own solution to a common problem!

Comment: The problem with a common solution is that everyone's application is totally different for handling: different input fields, different error messages, different message locations. I agree it would be great to have one thing handle all this, but it's just not feasible. The best solution is to use a great framework (Glad to see you moved to Sel2!) and good patterns of implementation for the test automation.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Any chance you could provide me with a reference on good patterns for website test automation in C#? I'm just learning the ropes and am looking for more constraints in the code I should be writing, so I do it right the first time. Thanks!

Comment: Read up on the Page Object pattern -- that concept is critical to understand. POP lets you avoid duplication of locators which is really critical to long-term maintenance and success. The second tip would be to read up on reading about synchronization or dealing with dynamic content such as AJAX calls. Those two things are the source 70% of the problems test automation folks have to deal with.